# Matlab: I have two points in a 3D plot and i want to connect them with a line

Tags: matlab, 3d, line, point, points

I have a 3D plot and two points coordinates A(0,0,0) and B(13,-11,19). I just want to plot a visible line connecting this two points ... I tried plot3(0,0,0, 13,-11,19) and other stuff but everything i tried failed miserably.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how:

```
% Your two points
P1 = [0,0,0];
P2 = [13,-11,19];

% Their vertial concatenation is what you want
pts = [P1; P2];

% Because that's what line() wants to see    
line(pts(:,1), pts(:,2), pts(:,3))

% Alternatively, you could use plot3:
plot3(pts(:,1), pts(:,2), pts(:,3))
```

Admittedly, this might seem a bit counter-intuitive at first, but in the long run it'll make sense.

If you read `doc plot` or `doc line`, you'll see that each expects *sets* of `x`, `y` and `z` data, respectively. That is, using

```
plot3(X,Y,Z)
```

with `X`, `Y` and `Z` some matrices, `plot3` will draw a line from the first *triplet* (`X(1) Y(1) Z(1)`) to the second triplet (`X(2) Y(2) Z(2)`)  and so on -- same for `line`.

Comment: The line(pts) didn't work (Not enough input arguments) but the plot3 works fine, now i understand how plot3 works...thanks dude!!!

Comment: @AntonioMartínezPalao: whoooops...sorry for that. I stand corrected!